# Create a human-readable list with "and" inserted before the last element from a ruby list

Tags: ruby

How would you take a list and make it into a comma-separated string, with "and" before the last element in the array?

Take something like:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
```

And turn it into this:

```
=> "a, b, and c"
```

I remember ruby had a method for this. I've searched however, and couldn't find it.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: +1 for using the Oxford comma!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try: `[list[0...-1].join(", "), list.last].join(", and ")`.

Edit: Rails has the method you were probably looking for, called [`to_sentence`](https://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence).

In case you do not have Rails or do not wish to depend on Rails, open `Array` class and include the above method, like:

```
class Array
  def join_all(join_with = ", ", connector = "and", last_comma = false)
    return self.to_s if self.empty? || self.size==1
    connector = join_with+connector if last_comma
    [list[0...-1].join(join_with), list.last].join(connector)
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's it! to_sentence does it.

Comment: @fl00r: obviously, thank you for pointing it. I updated the code, now it returns `self.to_s` when array has one element or is empty.

Comment: For the non-Rails folks you can `require 'active_support/core_ext/array/conversions'` to get to_sentence

Answer (score 7):

```
class Array
  def to_sentence
    sentence = self[0..-2].join(", ") + ", and " + self[-1].to_s if self.size > 1
    sentence ||= self.to_s
  end
end
```

so

```
[1].to_sentence
#=> "1"
[1,2,3].to_sentence
#=> "1, 2, and 3"
[].to_sentence
#=> ""
```

And in Rails here is [to_sentence](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence) method that uses I18n locales as well

Answer (score 0):

Might be a better way, but this would work:

```
class Array
  def to_human_string
    arr = Array.new(self)
    last = arr.pop
    arr.join(", ") + ", and " + last.to_s
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
['a','b','c'].to_human_string
=> "a, b, and c"
```

You could add options for the delimiter, the 'and' and the optional oxford comma.