# create comma separated string in the First element of an array Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

So this may seem odd, and I have done quite a bit of googling, however, I am not really a programmer, (sysops) and trying to figure out how to pass data to the AWS API in the required format, which does seem a little odd.

So, working with resources in AWS, I need to pass tags which are keys and values. The key is a string. The value is a comma separated string, in the first element of an array. So in Ruby terms, looks like this.

```
{env => ["stage,qa,dev"]}
```

and not

```
{env => ["stage","qa","dev"]}
```

I'm created an admittedly. not a very pretty little app that will allow me to run ssm documents on targeted instances in aws.

I can get the string into an array element using this class I created

```
class Tags

  attr_accessor :tags

  def initialize
    @tags    = {"env" => nil ,"os" => nil ,"group" => nil }
  end

  def set_values()
    puts "please enter value/s for the following keys, using spaces or commas for multiple values"
    @tags.each { |key,value|
    print "enter #{key} value/s: "
    @tags[key] = [gets.strip.chomp]
    @tags[key] = Validate.multi_value(tags[key])
    }
  end

end
```

I then call this Validate.multi_value passing in the created Array, but it spits an array of my string value back.

```
class Validate
  def self.multi_value(value)
      if value.any?{ |sub_string| sub_string.include?(",") || sub_string.include?(" ") }
         value = value[0].split(/[,\s]+/)
       return value
      else
       return value
     end

    end

end
```

Using pry, I've seen it gets for example `["stage dev qa"]` then the if statement does work, then it spits out `["stage","dev","qa"]`.

and I need it to output `["stage,dev,qa"]` but for the life of me, I can't make it work.

I hope that's clear.

If you have any suggestions, I'd be most grateful.

I'm not hugely experienced at ruby and the may be class methods that I've missed.

Comment: on a side note, see [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#lambda-multi-line) for multi-line block syntax, `@tags.each { |key,value|` should be `@tags.each do |key,value|` and close with `end` on last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your arrays are always coming through in the format `["stage dev qa"]` then first we need to split the one string into the parts we want:

```
arr = ["stage dev qa"]
arr.split(' ')
=> ["stage", "dev", "qa"]
```

Then we need to join them with the comma:

```
arr.split(' ').join(',')
=> "stage,dev,qa"
```

And finally we need to wrap it in an array:

```
[arr.first.split(' ').join(',')]
=> ["stage,dev,qa"]
```

All together:

```
def transform_array(arr)
  [arr.first.split(' ').join(',')]
end

transform_array(['stage dev qa'])
=> ['stage,dev,qa']
```

More info: [How do I convert an array of strings into a comma-separated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313613/how-do-i-convert-an-array-of-strings-into-a-comma-separated-string)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very elegant. I was sort of coming to that kind of conclusion, but very verbosely.

    `def self.multi_value(value)
      if value.any?{ |sub_string| sub_string.include?(",") || sub_string.include?(" ") }
         result = []
         value = value[0].split(/[,\s]+/)
         value = value.join(",")
         result[0] = value
       return result
      else
       return value
     end
    end`

Comment: You're welcome, and yup we were both pretty much on the same track :)

Comment: Why split the string on spaces then rejoin the pieces with commas rather than just converting the spaces to commas?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this?, everything gets treated in the Validates method. I don't know if you wanted to remove repeated values, but, just in case I did, so a

```
"this    string,, has too  many,,, , spaces"
```

will become

```
"this,string,has,too,many,spaces"
```

and not

```
"this,,,,string,,,has,too,,many,,,,,,spaces"
```

Here's the code

```
class Tags
  attr_accessor :tags

  # initializes the class (no change)
  #
  def initialize
    @tags = {"env" => nil ,"os" => nil ,"group" => nil }
  end

  # request and assign the values <- SOME CHANGES
  #
  def set_values
    puts "please enter value/s for the following keys, using spaces or commas for multiple values"
    @tags.each do |key,value|
      print "enter #{key} value/s: "
      @tags[key] = Validate.multi_value( gets )
    end
  end
end

class Validate
  # Sets the array
  #
  def self.multi_value(value)
    # Remove leading spaces, then remove special chars,
    # replace all spaces with commas, then remove repetitions
    #
    [ value.strip.delete("\n","\r","\t","\rn").gsub(" ", ",").squeeze(",") ]
  end
end
```

EDITED, thanks lacostenycoder

Comment: `.remove` is not defined in String class in core Ruby, but is provide by Rails's `active_support`.  You could however use `.delete` which is in [core Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/String.html#method-i-delete)

Answer (score 0):

I see no point in creating a class here when a simple method would do.

```
def set_values
  ["env", "os", "group"].map do |tag|
    puts "Please enter values for #{tag}, using spaces or commas"
    print "to separate multiple values: "
    gets.strip.gsub(/[ ,]+/, ',')
  end
end
```

Suppose, when asked, the user enters, `"stage dev,qa" (for`"env"`), "OS X" (for`"OS"`) and "Hell's Angels"` for `"group"`. Then:

```
set_values
  #=> ["stage,dev,qa", "OS,X", "Hell's,Angels"]
```

If, as I suspect, you only wish to convert spaces to commas for `"env"` and not for `"os"` or `"group"`, write:

```
def set_values 
  puts "Please enter values for env, using spaces or commas"
  print "to separate multiple values: "
   [gets.strip.gsub(/[ ,]+/, ',')] +
   ["os", "group"].map do |tag|
     print "Please enter value for #{tag}: "
     gets.strip
   end
end
```

```
set_values
  #=> ["stage,dev,ga", "OS X", "Hell's Angels"]
```

See [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-map), [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) and [Array#+](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-2B).

`gets.strip.gsub(/[ ,]+/, ',')` merely *chains* the two operations `s = gets.strip` and `s.gsub(/[ ,]+/, ',')`. Chaining is commonplace in Ruby.

The regular expression used by `gsub` reads, "match one or more spaces or commas", `[ ,]` being a *character class*, requiring one of the characters in the class be matched, `+` meaning that one or more of those spaces or commas are to be matched. If the string were `"a , b,,  c"` there would be two matches, `" , "` and `",,  "`; `gsub` would convert both to a single comma.

Using `print` rather than `puts` displays the user's entry on the same line as the prompt, immediately after `": "`, rather than on the next line. That is of course purely stylistic.

Often one would write `gets.chomp` rather than `gets.strip`. Both remove newlines and other whitespace at the end of the string, `strip` also removes any whitespace at the beginning of the string. `strip` is probably best in this case.